# PriorityQ Assistance

Tags: java, priority-queue

> I'm having problems with this code. I have to create a PriorityQ, that has fast O(1) insertion time but slower removal of the high priority item can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
public class PriorityQ {
private long[] pq;
private int nElems;

public void PQ() { 
    pq= new long[3];
    nElems=0;
    }

public boolean isEmpty() { return nElems==0;}

public void insert(long x) {
    pq[nElems++]=x;
}
public long remove(long x){
long max = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < nElems; i++)
            if (pq[i] == x) {
                max = pq[i];
                pq[i] = pq[--nElems];
                break;
            }

        return max;
}
 public static void main (String []args){
     PriorityQ theQ = new PriorityQ();
     theQ.insert (10);
     theQ.insert (20);
     theQ.insert (30);
     theQ.remove (10);

      for(int i=0; i<theQ.nElems; i++){
       System.out.print ("");
       System.out.print (theQ.pq[i]);
      }
```

}
       }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters, you aren't defining your constructor properly.

```
public void PQ() { 
pq= new long[3];
nElems=0;
}
```

should be more like

```
PriorityQ() { 
pq= new long[3];
nElems=0;
}
```